# Mantener Height

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Mi problemática es la siguiente.

```
    <div class="container-fluid overflow-auto contain">
        <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap">
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="head">
                    head
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                ..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tengo este contenedor que principalmete será destinado para llenarlo de cajas en los col-3 para un listado de opciones con cabecera e información.

El chiste es que lo que quiero hace parecer es que siempre se vaya a la derecha

le apliqué un absolute y le puse un cal() en .contain porque también tengo un slidebar

Pero quiero que la altura de todo ese div siempre esté de un mismo tamaño, osea el tamaño total de la página

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Va a ser un listado de claves en la que será dividido por categoría, de ahí los col-3

Comment: ¿Y si a ese div le aplicas un `height` de 100vh?

Comment: @Aprendiz ¿En si qué es vh? :o

Comment: Muchas gracias @Aprendiz c:

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que usar un min-height:100%; en le contenedor para que siempre te ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla